# How to get Node object when using Neo4j jdbc?

Tags: mongodb, transactions, neo4j

I used neo4j-rest-binding in my project, but I face some transaction issue, so I want to control transaction by my self. I found neo4j-jdbc is a good option, and it sounds have more pros than neo4j-rest-binding from the article in google forum. (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/4DG_R5Yh2BM)

I used neo4j-rest-binding to do query and I can transform the result to Node object.

```
QueryResult<Map<String, Object>> result = engine.query("MATCH (n) RETURN n")
Iterator<Node> nodeIter = result.to(Node.class).iterator();
// if I want to get the relationship of the node
Iterator<Relationship> outRelIter = node.getRelationships(Direction.OUTGOING).iterator();
...
```

But when I use neo4j-jdbc to do query, I don't know how to get Node object...

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("MATCH (n) RETURN n");
while(rs.next()) {  
    Map<String, Object> res = (Map<String, Object>) rs.getObject("n");
    // how to get Node object?
}
```

Another question is if I use `tx.fail()`, `tx.success()` and `tx.finish()`, how could I know when the transaction fail? I know it will rollback if `tx.success` is not called, but since I combine MongoDB and Neo4j, I want to rollback MongoDB when Neo4j fail. such like:

```
//Do some MongoDB operation...
...

//Do some Neo4j operation...
tx.begin();
try {
    ...
    if(???) // if transaction fail
        // rollback MongoDB
    else
        tx.success();
} finally {
    tx.close();
}
```

Does it work when I use neo4j-jdbc? (I have answered this question by myself)

```
try {
    conn.setAutoCommit(false); // for Neo4j
    //Do some MongoDB operation...
    ...

    //Do some Neo4j operation...
    conn.commit();
} catch(SQLException e) {
    conn.rollback(); // for Neo4j
    // rollback MongoDB
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you return a node from cypher it will be returned as a Map in the remote case, so you can use `(Map)rs.getObject("n")` to access the property.

If you use getString() you get a JSON representation instead.

If you need node-id's or -labels you have to return them explicitely, like this:

```
MATCH (n) 
RETURN { id : id(n), labels : labels(n), data: n } as node
```

Then again, you get a map back with the `id`, `labels` and the node-properties as `data` fields.

For controlling the transaction you use `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` and `connection.commit()` or `connection.rollback()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! If I want to get the related nodes, I have to make a query likes 'MATCH (n)-[]->(m) RETURN m' to get the information of related nodes. Is it right? I think neo4j-rest-binding is easier to use, since I can use embedded method to control the object. Could you tell me which is better you think? Many thanks.

Comment: Another question is: Sometimes errors may happen when commit data to neo4j (after calling `connection.commit()`), how could I know the commitment fail?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with your first comment "I think neo4j-rest-binding is easier to use, since I can use embedded method to control the object"

Comment: Since when i want to find the related node of node A, I could use `nodeA.getRelationships(Direction.OUTGOING).iterator();` to get the relationship, and then use the relation to get start and end node in neo4j-rest-binding. However, I have to use cypher to get the relationship in neo4j-jdbc. It is better to use java embedded methods of neo4j for me.

Comment: Note that in the new JDBC driver, you can just return `n` and it comes back as a map with `_id` and `_labels` entries.

Answer (score 2):

Cypher JDBC does not return nodes, instead it returns the properties of a node as you've seen. To get the node as a object:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("MATCH (n) RETURN id(n)");
while(rs.next()) {  
    long nodeId = (long) rs.getObject("id(n)");
    Node n = graphDb.getNodeById(nodeId);
}
```

However this works only in embedded mode. When using Cypher JDBC remotely there is no notion of nodes. Every operation in the graph should be done solely via Cypher.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Could you tell me neo4j-rest-binding or neo4j-jdbc is better when using neo4j remotely?

Comment: I have updated my question about transaction controller

Comment: there are no transactions with the java-rest-binding

Comment: The `tx.fail()` issue is for embedded case. I also want to know how to controller fail situation in neo4j-jdbc. I have a sudo code in my original post. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the transaction with Neo4j and MongoDB by yourself. You could use below structure:

```
try {
    conn.setAutoCommit(false); // for Neo4j
    //Do some Neo4j operation...

    //Do some MongoDB operation...

    conn.commit(); // if Mongo and Neo4j both success, data will be committed to Neo4j
} catch(SQLException e) {
    conn.rollback(); // for Neo4j
    // rollback MongoDB
}
```

Since MongoDB has it's own way to rollback in same document. If Neo4j success, but MongoDB fail. MongoDB will rollback and it will get an exception and neo4j will rollback too.
If Neo4j Fail, it will not execute mongo section.