# Neo4j-JDBC Driver only returns one row

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using the Neo4j JDBC driver 2.0.1.

When I run the following query on by browser, I get the right data back.

```
MATCH (u:Person) RETURN  u.name, u.lastname
```

I am executing this statement with the NeoJDBC driver (I am connected to the db, otherwise I would not have been able to create nodes before):

```
public static ResultSet executeCypher(String query)
{
        try (Statement stmt = TestUtils.connection.createStatement())
        {
            return stmt.executeQuery(query);
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "\n\n" + e.getCause().toString() + "\n\n" + e.getErrorCode());
        
        }
        
}
```

When I'm iterating over the result set, there are 2 colums as expected. But only one row in the result set. I wrote this according to [the minimum viable snippet](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc#minimum-viable-snippet):

```
//create some users here
//...
//check the database content
ResultSet rs = TestUtils.executeCypher("MATCH (u:Person) RETURN  u.name, u.lastname");
    while(rs.next())
    {
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("u.name"));
        System.out.println("print anything for test purposes"); 
        
    }
```

Output:

> Executing query: MATCH (u:Person) RETURN  u.name as name, u.lastname
> as lastname  with params {} Starting the Apache HTTP client
>
> John
> print anything for test purposes

Why do I only get one row back although it should return multiple rows? I found some data in the "data" field of the ResultSet while debugging (see also [Michael Hunger's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807691/how-to-get-node-object-when-using-neo4j-jdbc)) where the "last" property is false. So I guess there is more data. But I don't know how to extract it.

How can I get all the data that is in the ResultSet (using an iterator)?

Comment: are you connecting to a remote or embedded database?

Comment: can you perhaps share a project with a failing unit-test on github?

Comment: I'm connecting to a remote database.
Here is the link for a quick and dirty eclipse project.
An IllegalStateException is thrown when iterating over the result set:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u63p1ikafcvqtzc/AAArgan_Sg9skvK8EZlfyxi3a

Comment: I tried to figure the problem out. I guess it is a problem in the StreamingParser class. Parsing an array works perfectly fine, but getting the next row seems to be a problem. After parsing one row the parser always goes to the end of the object in the data array that is returned by the Neo server.
But I couldn't figure the exact location of the problem out.

Comment: @slashburn did you figure out the problem. How did you deal with it. I am in a similar situation.

Comment: I cloned the JDBC Driver project and tried to figure out the bug. Since it is quite complex I decided to take another library and switching to another language. Figuring the bug out would probaby have been extremely time consuming. Check http://www.anormcypher.org/ out. Quite cool. Much easier than the Java driver (only a few hundert LoC).
This is the only drawback of Neo4j. There are a lot of github projects but none of them are officially managed by Neo4j. I think there should be at least a Java version providing the basic functionality. Otherwise you have to deal with JSON parsing.